# How to connect Win 10 PC to Mini DisplayPort on Samsung SR75

Tags: hdmi, displayport

I have a desktop connected to my Samsung SR75 Space Monitor using an HDMI connector. I need to connect my laptop to the same monitor. However, the only port available on the monitor is the Mini DisplayPort. I tried connecting it with a Mini DisplayPort to HDMI connector, but the desktop's display is not showing up on the monitor.

How do I get the Win 10 PC's display on the monitor by using the Mini DisplayPOrt?

Comment: Obvious but need to ask: You've switched inputs on your monitor's menu, right? Also, you wrote "laptop" twice in the first sentence.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. I have my desktop connected to the Samsung monitor and I need to connect the laptop. Yes, I tried switching inputs on my monitor. However the cable I used is "Miniport to HDMI". It is unidirectional and an "HDMI to Miniport" cable doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered the same issue and didn't find solution yet. It seems mini-display port to hdmi is not sutable in this case because it's designed to connect your Mini DisplayPort equipped PC to a HDMI monitor, but DisplayPort to HDMI cables will only carry signals in one direction. As far as I understand you need HDMI to Displayport cable or bidirectional adapter.